# where is rabbitmq context user

Tags: macos, erlang, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, rabbitmq

After installing `rabbitmq` on mac (lion), the document says its context user is named `"rabbitmq"`. When trying to set up the named `"rabbitmq"` user through the OS's preference panel's account menu, it tells me that the account is already established, can't be created duplicatedly.
But when checking `/Users/` directory, I can't find the rabbitmq path. In addition, when check `/etc/passwd` configure file using command of `"cat /etc/passwd |grep rabbitmq"`. But the response is blank.

Could you tell me where is rabbitmq user? where to place `.erlang.cookie` file, and where to place `'.erlang'` file.

If possible, please tell me which source code file of `rabbitmq-server project` is responsible for creating the context user, I really want to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed rabbitmq through homebrew, and ran sudo rabbitmq-server.  The home directory was listed in the output:

```
AMQP 0-9-1 / 0-9 / 0-8
Copyright (C) 2007-2012 VMware, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

node           : rabbit@kelly-mac
app descriptor : /usr/sbin/../../opt/rabbitmq/sbin/../ebin/rabbit.app
home dir       : /Users/kjw
config file(s) : (none)
cookie hash    : <somehadh>
log            : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@kelly-mac.log
sasl log       : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@kelly-mac-sasl.log
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@kelly-mac
erlang version : 5.9
```

It looks like the home directory is set based on the user running rabbitmq.  Try putting your cookie and .erlang files in your home directory and see if that works.

Comment: It is this morning that I have checked it and the result is correct. Thank you very much.